# Process two excel files and download result in third excel file in flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a scenario where I take two excel files from two seaparate html input type file and process them and need to download the result on a click from the same UI.
I am using flask to process the form post requests.
Require help in structuring the code.

Comment: Try to break down your big task into smaller tasks. Each one then is much more doable.

Comment: Just implement the solution step by step. Afterwards you can refactor the code into a better structure. Make it work, first

Comment: Got this by by having the two input file types and the submit in a single form tag